# Check if the process exists before process.start();

Tags: c#, process, process.start

I made a little program that execute executable file  (.exe) but when you write down no existed file I get an error, the file specific not found.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to check if the process exists first before running it, and if it doesn't exist you can show a message box.

This is my code

```
 private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string text = textBox1.Text;
        Process process = new Process();
        if (!textBox1.Text.Contains(".exe"))
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = text + ".exe";
        }
        else
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = text;
        }
        process.Start();


    }
```

Comment: The process cannot exist before you create it. You mean the file.

Comment: @varocarbas Well I donnu exactly what you call it, but I'm talking about an executable file ...

Comment: I understood it. My comment was just a clarification. It is not how I call it but how .NET calls it: one thing is a file (the executable in this case; file in the hard-drive) and another thing is a process (the one created when the executable is run, for example; running program in the memory). You want to check if the file exists (= present in the given path; in the hard-drive) in order to create a process and run it (not if the process exists: it does not exist because you haven't created it yet).

Comment: thanks for this explication ^^
Well yes see if the path exists in the hard drive before running it.

Answer (score 2):

Check that file is exists before start process:

```
var processFileName = !textBox1.Text.Contains(".exe")
    ? text + ".exe"
    : text;

if (File.Exists(processFileName))
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.Start(processFileName);
}
```

Comment: ` if (File.Exists(text))
            {
                process.Start();
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("Not found", "");
            }
            `
but didn't work ... gives me the same problem !

Comment: I did use it but it gave me the same problem of mine, I mean there's no difference I guess ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:
->(You have to add #using System.IO; before using "File.Exists" command)

```
button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs )
{
            string exepath = "C:\\example\\example.xlsx";
            if(File.Exists(exepath))
            {
                Process.Start(exepath);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File not found!");
            }
}
```

Hope it's working !

You can string the path and string the filename in other string, and then you can even check the Folder, and if the folder exists ,then check the file!
Also you can use your textbox1 as filename, but you have to add the path, unless it will be search in the program directory.(bin/debug)
If i was wrong, forgive me, i am learning c# at the moment!
Have a good day!